# Suppress python logger for a specific requests call

Tags: python, logging, python-requests

I am using `session.request` call multiple time at multiple places. I want to block its log for a specific call. How can I achieve that. I figured that we can block it for all the requests call using following method

```
logging.basicConfig(filename=filename,
                            format='%(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                            filemode='a')

logger = logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING) # To disable requests logging info

def fun1():
    session.request('POST', _endpoint, json=data)

def fun2():
    session.request('POST', _endpoint, json=data)
```

I want to disable logs for `fun1` but keep it running for `fun2`. Is it possible to customize logs in such a way that I can disable them for a particular function of call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work. You can also turn it into a decorator.

```
def fun1():
    logging.disable() # globally stops all logs with level critical or lower (so all logs)
    session.request('POST', _endpoint, json=data)
    logging.disable(logging.NOTSET) # remove the override
```

Comment: I got the error `AttributeError: 'RootLogger' object has no attribute 'disable'`

Comment: did you call `logging.disable()` or `logger.disable()`? disable is a module level method, not of the logger

Comment: okay, Thanks. I called `logger.disable()`